# 'CTCTrainer' object has no attribute 'use_amp'

Tags: python, large-language-model, huggingface, pre-trained-model, huggingface-trainer

i am trying to run a pretrained model and i found this code thats similar to what im trying to do , when i try to run it i get an error

here are some bits of code to understand the context

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Union

import torch
from packaging import version
from torch import nn

from transformers import (
    Trainer,
    is_apex_available,
)

if is_apex_available():
    from apex import amp

if version.parse(torch.__version__) >= version.parse("1.6"):
    _is_native_amp_available = True
    from torch.cuda.amp import autocast


class CTCTrainer(Trainer):
    def training_step(self, model: nn.Module, inputs: Dict[str, Union[torch.Tensor, Any]]) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        Perform a training step on a batch of inputs.

        Subclass and override to inject custom behavior.

        Args:
            model (:obj:`nn.Module`):
                The model to train.
            inputs (:obj:`Dict[str, Union[torch.Tensor, Any]]`):
                The inputs and targets of the model.

                The dictionary will be unpacked before being fed to the model. Most models expect the targets under the
                argument :obj:`labels`. Check your model's documentation for all accepted arguments.

        Return:
            :obj:`torch.Tensor`: The tensor with training loss on this batch.
        """

        model.train()
        inputs = self._prepare_inputs(inputs)

        if self.use_amp:
            with autocast():
                loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
        else:
            loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)

        if self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps > 1:
            loss = loss / self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps

        if self.use_amp:
            self.scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        elif self.use_apex:
            with amp.scale_loss(loss, self.optimizer) as scaled_loss:
                scaled_loss.backward()
        elif self.deepspeed:
            self.deepspeed.backward(loss)
        else:
            loss.backward()

        return loss.detach()
```

```
trainer.train()
```

i get 'CTCTrainer' object has no attribute 'use_amp' and when i use use_cuda_amp instead of use_amp

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Union

import torch
from packaging import version
from torch import nn

from transformers import (
    Trainer,
    is_apex_available,
)

if is_apex_available():
    from apex import amp

if version.parse(torch.__version__) >= version.parse("1.6"):
    _is_native_amp_available = True
    from torch.cuda.amp import autocast


class CTCTrainer(Trainer):
    def training_step(self, model: nn.Module, inputs: Dict[str, Union[torch.Tensor, Any]]) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        Perform a training step on a batch of inputs.

        Subclass and override to inject custom behavior.

        Args:
            model (:obj:`nn.Module`):
                The model to train.
            inputs (:obj:`Dict[str, Union[torch.Tensor, Any]]`):
                The inputs and targets of the model.

                The dictionary will be unpacked before being fed to the model. Most models expect the targets under the
                argument :obj:`labels`. Check your model's documentation for all accepted arguments.

        Return:
            :obj:`torch.Tensor`: The tensor with training loss on this batch.
        """

        model.train()
        inputs = self._prepare_inputs(inputs)

        if self.use_cuda_amp:
            with autocast():
                loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)
        else:
            loss = self.compute_loss(model, inputs)

        if self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps > 1:
            loss = loss / self.args.gradient_accumulation_steps

        if self.use_cuda_amp:
            self.scaler.scale(loss).backward()
        elif self.use_apex:
            with amp.scale_loss(loss, self.optimizer) as scaled_loss:
                scaled_loss.backward()
        elif self.deepspeed:
            self.deepspeed.backward(loss)
        else:
            loss.backward()

        return loss.detach()
```

i get 'CTCTrainer' object has no attribute 'use_cuda_amp'